# How to Read in a String With Spaces into a Linked List?

Tags: c++, string, linked-list

So essentially I am reading data into this linked list, then after each node is inserted (front or back) I display the nodes. When I do this, everything works fine with names without spaces, but if I use first and last with a space it does not function properly and will separate the string(s) with spaces into 2 different nodes, usually opposite of each other. Here is my code to read the data that is entered:

```
    struct node *new_node() {
    
        struct node *new1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
        cin >> new1 -> string_val;
        new1 -> next=NULL;
    
        return new1;
    }
```

The constructor for the struct 'node' is as follows:

```
        struct node {
            char string_val[20];
            struct node *next;
        };
```

Comment: Tip: In C++ prefer `nullptr` to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++.  Or do you intend to write "C" code?
Node should have a constructor and a member to hold the value, and creation of nodes should be in a list class (so it can do all the proper administration).
User input should not be part of the node class.  In production code, just use std::list

Comment: Is the name all on one line? Use `std::getline`.

Comment: *The constructor for the struct 'node' is as follows:* -- That is not a constructor.  It certainly does look like you are using `C` material and attempting to use it in a C++ program.  Also, if you change that type to `std::string` instead of `char [20]`, that `malloc` call falls apart and cannot be used.

Comment: Also, if you're using C++ rather than C, the `struct` in `struct node *next;` is unnecessary. You can just: `node *next;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the node definition needs to be the same and input is through `stdin` and all one one line for the following answer.  Due to use of `char [20]` input from `stdin` is truncated to prevent overflow or segfault.

Given the following node (preserving OP's node definition):

```
struct node {
    char string_val[20];
    struct node *next;
};
```

Node can be constructed with following:

```
struct node *new_node() {
    // Create new node
    node * newNode = new node;

    // Get line
    std::cin.getline(newNode->string_val, 20);

    // Set next node to nullptr
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    return newNode;
}
```

If node definition can be changed and `std::string` can be used then this changes to the following:

```
#include <string>

struct node {
    std::string string_val;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *new_node() {
    // Create new node
    struct node * newNode = new node;

    // Get line
    std::getline(std::cin, newNode->string_val);

    newNode->next = nullptr;

    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Since the OP wants to use a `char[]` instead of `std::string` in the node, you can avoid using a temp `std::string` by using `cin.getline()` instead of `std::getline()`. Especially since your use of `strcpy()` will overflow the `char[]` if `input.size()` is >= 20 as you are not accounting for the null terminator correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau indeed.  Corrected.  Thanks.